# Proper way to reinstall iOS app between XCTest runs (via simctl)

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode10, reinstall, simctl

When running UI test suite I need to reinstall the app between tests. It was going well with `simctl uninstall booted #appId` until **XCode 10**. Now after the app has been uninstalled the next test fails with:

> This app could not be installed at this time.
>
> Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/###/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/###/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.###/extracted/Payload/###.app

Looks like Apple made some "optimization" in Xcode 10 for app caching. `simctl` deletes the app from `Cache` directory and `XCtest` tries to install it from that place.

I'm looking for advises how to fix this issue. I prefer keep uninstalling the app via `simctl` over deleting it from Springboard for simplicity reason.